# Excel INDEX MATCH retrieves information randomly

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I'm have an issue that the Excel INDEX (with double MATCH) funtion retrieves data what it seems randomly. I have the following [data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD7P9.png) (Imgur).

**What it needs to do:** Display the pax count on the schedule at the correct position if a match between the gatenumber (columA) and the time (row1) is found in the data list.

I used:  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($I$54:$I$91,MATCH($A2&I$1,$H$54:$H$91&$G$54:$G$91,0)),"")}`

**The issue:** some values are retrieved, some not (marked in gray) without any differences in the function/data.

Remarks:

- All cell formats are the same.
- All cells are set as an array {}.
- Increasing the Index Array to all 3 columns with the data and adding [column_num] 3 does not help.
- If I change values like the time in the list some move to the correct new position, some not.
- Software version is (Excel) Professional Plus 2013.

Any help on what the cause of this problem could be, a solution or an alternative method would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use ctrl+shift+enter to enter the formula. It is doing an array operation(concatenation)

Comment: Hi MarcoMarc, I have done that. Every cell has the {}.

Comment: what happens when you try to evaluate parts of the formula with F9 on the missing values? Also are there any rogue spaces in the gate text?

Comment: When evaluating, I get this: http://i.imgur.com/o0qNtAQ.png

I have changed the gates to numbers to rule out possible spaces.

Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Really need to see the arguments to the functions evaluated 'as one', not piecemeal. So evaluate all the match arguments. Highlight everything between each set of brackets, NOT each cell reference

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is what you mean. http://i.imgur.com/6VWajM2.png

It looks like the time in row1 differs very slightly (0.236111111111112 vs. 0.236111111111111) from what is in the data list and with 0 set as match type is does not make an exact match

Comment: There's your problem - precision in floats. So use round function(maybe to about 5 places) on the values in the time parts of the function. Comparing floats for equality can be problematic.

Comment: Or you could convert times to text =IFERROR(INDEX($I$54:$I$91,MATCH($A2&TEXT(I$1,"HH:MM"),$H$54:$H$91&TEXT($G$54:$G$91,"HH:MM"),0)),"")

Comment: Thanks guys for the input! Issue is solved :)